# Unit of Measure "Type" in F#

Tags: c#, f#

I am writing a conversion function for units of measurements in F#. The information regarding the values is coming from an ASP.NET web application.

The function I am creating is defined like this:

```
let convert (x:float<_>) (toType : string) =
  // Do conversion here.
```

The first problem I am running into involves the toType : string definition. Is there any way I can make define it to accept a `float<_>` type...particularly coming from the web application? (I know it's part of the CLR based on [Andrew Kennedy's excellent articles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andrewkennedy/archive/2008/08/29/units-of-measure-in-f-part-one-introducing-units.aspx), but I don't see how to generically define it in the function.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking or trying to do.

Comment: @Brian - Basically, I want to convert values based on a Measurement type. Based on the answer from @kvb, it seems like I may not be able to as the information is erased at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to be able to read in "2.0 ft" and "5.0 m" then

- you should write code that parses the strings and does some conditional logic (e.g. if "ft" then turn into `float<ft>` or whatever)
- once you have the data converted into the F# type system you can do things in a typesafe way

This is typical of every app that wants to get strongly-typed data in from the outside world; there is an input component that must parse and validate the input and store it into a strongly-typed data structure, but then the program can use that data henceforth.

(There's no magical parser/input validator in any library, you just do it for your data types.)

Comment: Okay, thank you for the answer. I thought this might be the solution, but I was hoping I could pass around the type directly instead of having to write the logic for each individual type (as this can become a maintenance nightmare). Thank you for providing this answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's going to be possible to do what you want since measure types are erased at runtime.  In particular, there's nothing analogous to a runtime type-test (such as F#'s (:?) operator) for measure types.

What type of logic were you hoping to implement inside your `convert` function?

**UPDATE**

Based on the additional information you've provided, here are some more thoughts:

1. The whole point of F#'s units of measure is to enforce, at compile time, that quantities are used in unit-appropriate ways.  This means that you can't write function `convert : float<'t> -> float<'u>` - what would happen if your users tried to perform a nonsensical conversion (like converting something from `float<kg>` to `float<m/s^2>`)?  The job of F#'s unit types is to statically prevent conversions like that.
2. **However**, if you have a known list of inter-convertible types, you can perform conversions which result in a non-unit-generic return type by just using multiplication:

   ```
   [<Measure>] type m
   [<Measure>] type km


   let convert (f:float) (s:string) : float<m> =
     match s with
     | "m" -> f * 1.0<m>
     | "km" -> f * 1.0<km> * 1000.0<km/m>
     | _ -> failwith (s |> sprintf "Unknown unit of measure: %s")
   ```

   This always returns a result in meters based on a unitless quantity and the name of the units that it represents.

Comment: I have a web application (scientific application) which takes in a lot of user-entered data. However, users may enter data in different units depending on where the data came from. As a result, I have to allow users to be able to convert between the units that they want to work in. I was hoping I could utilize F#, or something that is already part of the .NET framework. FOSS libraries are not generally an option, unfortunately.

Comment: Well, `convert : float<'t> -> float<'u>` can definitely make sense. The example above, converting feet to meters, is a prime candidate:
`let footToMeter (x: float<ft>) = x * 0.3048<m/ft>`. And a generic function could match generic input against certain types (including their units of measure) and throw an exception in case of an invalid conversion.